# Digital signature using bouncy castle and certificate private key

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I am developing a feature to digital sign some content. I have valid certificate with a private key. How to digital sign using the private key and bouncy castle?

I tried the following but want some right way to achieve the same using bouncy castle:

```
X509Certificate2 signingCert =
    CryptoHelper.FindCertificate("21A6107EC254457AAF3D4D6FD286FB79");

var rsaObj = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)signingCert.PrivateKey;
_privateKey = rsaObj.ExportParameters(true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't even contain any signature generation. And SO is not a service to write code for you.

Comment: @stackers Yes, that's me...any question or comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don´t know exactly what you need based on your code, but there X509 namespace/code is at
[bcgit/bc-csharp - X509](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/tree/master/crypto/src/x509)  and there is an utility class for conversion between `System.Security.Cryptography` and `BouncyCastle`
[bcgit/bc-csharp - DotNetUtilities.cs](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/security/DotNetUtilities.cs)

BouncyCastle got lots of test (and examples). Have a look at [bcgit/bc-csharp - TestCertificateGen.cs](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/test/src/x509/test/TestCertificateGen.cs) too. Maybe this helps you.

EDIT: In general it should go something like this

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

// Your loaded certificate
X509Certificate cert = null;             

// Your loaded RSA key   
AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = null;

AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = cert.GetPublicKey();

ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner(cert.SigAlgName);

// Init for signing, you pass in the private key
signer.Init(true, privateKey);

// Init for verification, you pass in the public key
signer.Init(false, publicKey);
```

Greetings

Comment: Thanks. Basically i have the certificate and have the private key from the certificate.I want to digital sign a string using bouncy castle.